# Looking for open-source and commercial tools for annotating RGB images with 3D bounding boxes or 6D pose (3D bbox + 3D rotation matrix)

Tags: open-source, 3d, computer-vision, annotation, deep-learning

I am trying to create ground truth for a custom data so that I can test the accuracy of my 6 Degree of Freedom (6 Dof) pose estimation algorithms on my custom data (that has no instance in famous 6D pose or 3D pose datasets such as YCB-V or LINEMOD).

I am looking for both commercial as well as open-source tools, commercial software, and vendors that does this task. I would like to know the tools (open-source or commercial) that would enable me to do this task along with vendors I could outsource this task to them. What are your suggestion?

Requirements for 3D bounding box annotation is the 3D coordinates of a tight bounding box encompassing the object of interest.

Requirements for 6 DoF pose annotation is the 3D coordinates of a tight bounding box encompassing the object of interest along with 3D rotation matrix to showcase the orientation of the object.